# How to disable "Power saving" mode programmatically. (Android)

Tags: java, android, mobile, opengl-es, power-management

Currently I'm trying to develop a **2D game for Android** devices by **using OpenGL ES**, but Android OS makes it as painful as possible.

It look very **nice and smoothly running at 60FPS** by consuming all the battery it can. Then suddenly I've realized that. Enabling "**Power save**" mode (**Galaxy S III**, etc), couses **FPS drop to 40**.

So I've **decided to increase game speed and limit timer to 40FPS**, so it will be possible to play at 40FPS smoothly.

And here comes another problem. This times **objects that moves are flickering** randomly even if the max is FPS set to 30 and calculation/drawings are on the same thread. when "**Power save**" is disabled(Disabled from devices menu) it keep running smoothly.

In short "**Power save**" mode is slowing down app **by slowing down OpenGL ES functions randomly even if it is not nessecery to drop FPS to 40**. (sometimes a function that takes 2-3ms to execute, takes 13-14ms and the others are running normaly)

**I wonder if there is a way to disable "Power save" mode in code and enable it back on exit.**

PS: To keep screen on I'm using next lines:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");
    this.mWakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: 40 fps is plenty. and you can just add a warning for the user advising to deactivate the power save mode (or even, prevent access to the game unless the power save mode is deactivated). This way, you won't drain the battery of the unknowing user.

Comment: Well 40 fps would be acceptable but I can't detect if Power save is enable or not. So I might check the FPS to detect but I think disabling PSave while app is running would be better then forcing users to do so.

Answer (score 2):

May be this helps you :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```